# Viewing Flash Applications on a Mac: stage.stageWidth/stage.stageHeight Return 0 in Firefox/IE

Tags: macos, flash, swfobject, stage

I am using SWFOBJECT to embed my flash content.

I have been worried about stage.stageWidth and stage.stageHeight returning 0 in Firefox/Internet Explorer; this problem is referred to in question #21 on the SWFOBJECT FAQ 
(http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/faq).

I have been told that this problem is particularly prevelant on Macs.

The SWFOBJECT FAQ (question 21) indirectly suggests that this problem does not occur with
static publishing.  Is this correct?  Is it still advisable to implement a solution
to this stageWidth/stageHeight problem, even if you are using static publishing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer this at least indirectly, with a workaround.

Do you have to use stage.stageWidth and stage.stageHeight? Could you instead just use a fixed number of pixels? If so, the problem goes away.

See here --

[swfobject weird behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772270/swfobject-weird-behavior)

and also

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/issues/detail?id=327